# Как кикнуть всех участников с сервера? JavaScript Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

Нужно чтоб бот кикнул абсолютно всех с сервера дискорд

Comment: один вопрос: ЗАЧЕМ?

Comment: @Lofectr. (¬‿¬)

Answer (score 2):

Если реализовывать это с помощью команды, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
   bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'masskick') {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return
        message.guild.members.map(member => {
            member.kick()
                .then(() => console.log(`Kicked ${member.displayName}`))
                .catch(console.error);
        })
    }
});
```